# Is it possible to create an NSSortDescriptor for a dictionary value in an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an object with a dictionary property. I want to sort by a value in the dictionary, lets say,

```
myObject.dictionary[@"sort"]
```

I have an array of these objects. Is it possible to create an NSSortDescriptor to sort by that value? Like,

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dictionary['sort']" ascending:YES]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and very normal to sort an array of objects like that.
You can simply create the sort descriptor in the following way:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dictionary.sort" ascending:YES];
```

"dictionary.sort" will be used as keyPath for sorting your object.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. This must be some sort of inherent knowledge of key/value coding because I couldn't find this documented anywhere.